# Oldest library in America?

Tags: history-of-literature

What’s the oldest free public library in North America?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This article](http://www.sturgislibrary.org/history/oldest-library/) provides a couple of options, depending on your exact definitions of "oldest," "free," "public," and "library." There is not a complete consensus. Note that the source for many of these is the library's own website, so ymmv.

**The Library Company of Philadelphia**, founded **1731**: first subscription library (aka, membership dues), but did allow borrowing books for free.

**The Darby Library**, founded **1743**: the oldest library in continuous service, but was a subscription library until the late 1800s.

**The Redwood Library and Athenæum**, founded **1746**: oldest library building continuously in use; originally a subscription library.

**The Library Company of Burlington**, founded 1757: originally a subscription library, but was the first to construct a library building, in **1789**.

**The Franklin Public Library**, founded **1790**: originally a collection of books donated to a town by Ben Franklin and lent to citizens free of charge.

**The Scoville Memorial Library**, founded **1803**: the first library to be open to the public free of charge.

**The Peterborough Town Library**, founded **1833**: the oldest free tax-supported public library.

**The Boston Public Library**, founded **1844**: first publicly supported free municipal library.

Bonus:

**The Sturgiss Library**: oldest *building* that currently houses a library, built **1644**--however, the library itself is newer.

Comment: I love how nitpicky this answer is!

Comment: @CJSheu Gotta anticipate the commenters ;-)